# find the matching string key and increment its value in json file using bash

Tags: json, linux, bash, unix, scripting

A json file has a line in the following format.
**`"solution-id": 1`**

And this line is repeated 1000 times in the file. Now I need to modify the line such that file looks like as follows

```
"solution-id": 1
"solution-id": 2
"solution-id": 3
...
....
.....
""solution-id": 1000"
```

How can i achieve this using bash or python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manipulating JSON with Bash or Python, you could use `jq`.
For example if you have JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "solution-id": "foo",
    "junk": "foo"
  },
  {
    "solution-id": "bar",
    "junk": "foo"
  }
]
```

And you want to transform into this:

```
[
  {
    "solution-id": 0,
    "junk": "foo"
  },
  {
    "solution-id": 1,
    "junk": "foo"
  }
]
```

You can write:

```
jq 'to_entries | map(.value["solution-id"] = .key) | map(.value)' file.json
```

What's happening here is, the `to_entries` function takes an array input, and generates key-value pairs, where key is a sequence of numbers 0, 1, 2, ..., n, and value is the original item in the array. The first `map` in the pipeline is to modify the value with the sequence number, the second `map` is to extract the value. To understand better, run just `jq to_entries' file.json`, the mappings will make more sense.

Comment: Thanks @janos.! Works fine as per my requirement.
But tried to interpret what actually is happening with "map(.value)" in the command.

Comment: @hruday this is what `to_entries` does: it takes an array input, and generates key-value pairs, where key is a sequence of numbers 0, 1, 2, ..., n, and value is the original item in the array. The first map in the pipeline is to modify the value with the sequence number, the second map is to extract the value. To understand better, run just `jq to_entries' file.json`, the mappings will make more sense.